# create setup for an existent exe file

Tags: setup-project, installshield-2010

I want to create a setup for an existent .exe file. This file needs some .ocx and .dll files to run correctly. So this mentioned setup should paste these all files in a specified path and then run the .exe file.

I have tried with installshield 2010 basic and InstallScript projects but i could not create some of dialogs in the format that i wanted.

Is there any way to create this setup? Or any one may help me to work with installshield?

Answer (score 0):

You might find working with another setup program easier, try the [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It has a RegDLL function:

RegDLL "$WINDIR\OCX\vbalGrid6.ocx"

if you need that also.

Comment: Hi gmlime,Tanx for your reply.can you please describe this software, because i do not have any imagine about it!!!